# How do I reference a Dynamically named MSI file in a Wix Bundle

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am using Wix 3.9 and have it building 3 MSI files and then a Bundle that includes each of the MSI files in succession.  I have upgraded the primary Installer project to automatically include version number in the MSI file name using the techniques described [here](http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2009/05/03/38.aspx) and [here](http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2010/08/05/99.aspx).  My BeforeBuild task in my Wix project is as follows (from second link)

```
<!-- Set Output file name to include version-->
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(SolutionDir)WindowsClient\bin\$(Configuration)\MyApp.exe">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersions" />
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <CreateProperty Value="$(OutputName)%(AssemblyVersions.Version)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetName"/>
  </CreateProperty>
  <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetFileName"/>
  </CreateProperty>
  <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetPath"/>
  </CreateProperty>
</Target>`
```

But this is causing my bundle to fail at the following line.

```
<MsiPackage Id="MyMsiFile" Name="$(var.WixInstaller.TargetFileName)" SourceFile="$(var.WixInstaller.TargetDir)"/>
```

It fails saying it cannot find the file MyMsiFile.msi, which is true because it is now named MyMsiFile1.0.1.msi.  How can I reference the MSI file with the dynamic name in the Bundle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up avoiding the question all together.  I changed my msi project to copy the msi and attach the version number to the copy.  This way I get one msi file with the version number and one without for bundling into more complete installers.  I removed the BeforeBuild code posted above and replaced it with this

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(SolutionDir)WindowsClient\bin\$(Configuration)\MyApp.exe">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersions" />
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <Copy SourceFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName).msi" DestinationFiles=".\bin\$(Configuration)\$(OutputName)%(AssemblyVersions.Version).msi" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way…

Modify the project that generates the MyMsiFile MSI file to also generate a MyMsiFile.wxs that defines a `PackageGroup` containing that package with its current name.

Then for bundle projects that need it, add the MyMsiFile.wxs as a [linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) file and in their bundle chain, reference the MSI with a `PackageGroupRef`.

This method keeps detailed knowledge of the MSI package in the MSI project and away from the bundle projects.

Comment: Can you provide code/a link to the first part of your answer?

Comment: How are you creating the filename of the MSI file?

Comment: Using the 'BeforeBuild' method in the second link I provided in my question.